# Sequelize Connect ETIMEOUT when connecting to remote mysql db

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting error `SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT` when trying to connect to a remote mysql db with sequelize.

Connection can be established successfully when I try to connect to my local mysql db.

I'm using sequelize's default db connection code `new Sequelize(...)` contained within models/index.js, with the following config (filled up with the correct values):

```
"production": {
  "username": "root",
  "password": null,
  "database": "database_production",
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "dialect": "mysql"
}
```

I tried connecting to the remote db with a simple php script and it worked (so we can rule out issues on the remote db server side)

Any ideas?

Comment: You said your production system is a remote system, but your host above is 127.0.0.1.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 5):

For me, I have to:

1) Define exact information of my database at the local server (Xamp/ Mamp). It means I must have the existing database to connect, user name and password is a privileged account in your database.

2) Xamp/ Mamp must be online (of course). Default ports will be taken by this local server, so try a different port for mysql `8889` instead of `3306`.

And this is what I tried:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize('wohui', 'root', 'root', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8889
});

sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
        });
```

Comment: That's great to log the sequlize connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in my case it happened because I forgot to open the connection to mysql port 3306 in the inbound rules at my cloud provider

Comment: that was my issue, and it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

This error usually appears when the connection to the sql server is not established. Some things to take care of are :

1. Ensure mysql server is running in the host you are trying to connect to.
2. Ensure the host ip is correct.
3. Ensure that the port entered is correct.
4. Ensure that the firewall rules are defined correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons for this, Listing out a few I have faced,

- Remote root access not granted by the mysql server.
- The configs are filtered by the environment, Which ideally is done by using the NODE_ENV variable, can you try running your server locally with prod config. In my case, I would do something like `NODE_ENV=production node server.js`. Assuming `server.js` is the start file. You can try logging the value's before `new Sequelize(...)`, that might give a better idea as to what's going in.

Comment: Finally figured out that the remote mysql server was not set up to accept incoming connections from outside its network!

Comment: can u tell me where and how to check and change that remote server action

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. While in my case I gave a wrong port number (I didn't update my port number for the production database)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my problem was in the ports. MySql had ports 3306 and in the config, i wrote port 3000 :D
Thanks for helped

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33484806)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. But in my case, my IP address hasn't been added to the Inbound Security Group in AWS.

To check that, do the following:

1. Go to AWS console
2. Security Groups
3. Click Security Group ID
4. Edit Inbound Rules
5. Add rule, select My IP from source selection.
6. Save

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the third way of how to connect to mysql database did not work (from official documentation), but the first one did.

Documentation:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

// Option 1: Passing a connection URI
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:') // Example for sqlite
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname') // Example for postgres

// Option 2: Passing parameters separately (sqlite)
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});

// Option 3: Passing parameters separately (other dialects)
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'postgres' | 'sqlite' | 'mariadb' | 'mssql' | 'db2' | 'snowflake' | 'oracle' */
});
```

My code that worked:

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  "mysql://my_username:my_password@my_host_with.com:my_port/my_database_schema"
); // Example for mysql

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database: ", error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issues some days back and I eventually noticed that it was because I was connected to a VPN when Every I disconnected from the VPN MySQL connection worked just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).