# why do i get [sequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: nodejs-server

ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT
at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/ec2-user/group1-vue-mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/ec2-user/group1-vue-mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)

Tried changing ports but still the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check the following question it might help you to find your answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713590/sequelize-connect-etimeout-when-connecting-to-remote-mysql-db